# Splitting a short exact sequence of orthogonal groups

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

How does one split the short exact sequence
$$1 \rightarrow SO_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow O_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{\pm 1\} \rightarrow 1$$
?

I understand that there needs to be an injective homomorphism from $\{\pm 1\}  \rightarrow O_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that the composition of this map with the map $O_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ equals the identity map, but I'm not sure how to construct this homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Just view $1$ as the identity matrix $I_n$, $-1$ as the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{rl}-1&0\\0&I_{n-1}\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Could you elaborate? I thought i'd seen this before.... couldn't you map $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ to its determinant, and for $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$ use the (trivial) inclusion map?

Comment: Yes, you map $O_n(\Bbb R)$ to $\{\pm1\}$ by determinant and the splitting map $\rho$ is defined as above. Then the composition would be $\det \rho(1)=\det I_n=1$